# Different error when I run the same tensorflow-r1.0 program twice

Tags: python, tensorflow

At the first time I run my program and I got the error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value noise_z/0__mnn/bias1

But when I run it again, the error became:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value noise_z/1__mnn/0weight_

Please note that the variable name is different. It is very annoying to debug. I wonder why this happens and how can I fix it?

Here is the code involved with the error:

```
with tf.variable_scope('noise_z'):
    for noise_idx in range(num_noise):
        noise = gaussian_sampler(mu_noise, var_noise, 1)
        noise_vec = multi_layer_nn(noise, [dim_noise, 64, embedding_size], name=str(noise_idx)+'_')
        noise_vecs.append(noise_vec)

def fully_con_layer(input_, fan_in, fan_out, name, initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer()):
    w = tf.get_variable(name+'_weight_', shape=[fan_in, fan_out], initializer=initializer)
    b = tf.get_variable('bias'+name, [fan_out], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
    return tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(input_, w)+b)

def multi_layer_nn(input_, num_unit_each_layer, name, initializer=tf.orthogonal_initializer()):
    x = input_
    num_layer = len(num_unit_each_layer)-1
    for layer in range(num_layer):
        with tf.variable_scope(name+'_'+"mnn"):
            x = fully_con_layer(x, num_unit_each_layer[layer], num_unit_each_layer[layer+1], str(layer))
    return x
```

Comment: Do you reset your graph before re-running it? `tf.reset_default_graph()`

Comment: @Tasos Thanks for your reply! But I run the program by `python xxx.py` Why do I need to insert the this code into the program to run it again?

Comment: I thought you may run it on a notebook. I see the errors are for different variables each time. What do you get if you use `tf.initialize_all_variables()`?

Comment: @Tasos I run it in the terminal. Indeed I have already do `init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()` and `sess.run(init_op)` before I call the above function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `tf.global_variables_initializer()` and `sess.run(init_op)` before you call the function (as you say you do in your comment), the variables defined in the function will be not initialized. You have to run `sess.run(init_op)` after all variables are defined.